# cannot await sync task

Tags: c#, mongodb

I try the following piece of code and got an error "Cannot await 'MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluent'
". Can anyone tell me why? What have I missed?
Thanks,

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var blogContext = new BlogContext();
    var recentPosts = await blogContext.Posts.Find(new BsonDocument());
    var model = new IndexModel
    {
        RecentPosts = recentPosts
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Is there a `FindAsync` method? You can't await synchronous stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the mongodb driver documentation here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver and here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/what_is_new/

You need have an awaitable result, which you can apparently get by using `ToListAsync()` as in:

```
var recentPosts = await blogContext.Posts.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
```